# How to export save game in DRM free Hacknet version?

Tags: linux, hacknet

Do you know where find save file in DRM free version (to be more fun in Linux;)).
I need to export my savegame to other machine.

Comment: check program files or %appdata% or even %localappdata%, look for your game folder or "virtualstore" if 32bit

Answer (score 1):

Quote from pcgamingwiki.com:

> Windows:   \Accounts
>   OS X:   ~/Library/Application Support/Hacknet/Accounts
>   Linux:  $XDG_DATA_HOME/Hacknet/Accounts
>   Steam:  \userdata\57979455\365450\remote\

Comment: Thanks for tip @sh4dow. Unfortunately, no matter how strange it is, I haven't got any Accounts folder in my Linux Hacknet installation... I have only Content, locales, mono, lib, lib64 directories and nothing named Accounts in it. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Savegame should be in content probably - and maybe it is. But how to verify that specific file is the right one (cannot found any files with names regarding to 'save' or to my account name)? Do you know what extension am I looking for (of course if we're assuming that one file will do the job)?

Comment: Eh, for a while I thought I'm smarter than I am ;) try to play a while, save and do ls -lR on Hacknet dir. But no files has been changed after last play. In fact, there are only few files which are new (since day I've installed Hacknet) here. But these are only settings, debug and lib files...

Comment: if you were using steam it should be somewhere in Steam/userdata/<userid>/<appid>/; other than that i have no idea where the saves could be. on windows, the file name seems to be save<username>.xml

Comment: On Ubuntu, where XDG_DATA_HOME is not set, look in .local/share/Hacknet/Accounts